# The response on postman is not clean

Tags: postman

[image: Screenshot from Postman]

When I enter a URL I get a 200 OK status and the desired output in my Anypoint Studio IDE. But the result on postman UI is like in the above image (link). Can anyone help me to get a readable output?

Comment: **Small clue:** seems issue with UTF-8, check how to fix that on java?